# How to handle security (authn/authz) with DGS Subscriptions and spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I'm mirroring a question asked directly on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/discussions/1644).

I'm up to the point where if I `authorize("/subscriptions",permitAll)` while configuring my `SecurityWebFilterChain` then I can successfully use my subscription queries. However, that removes all the security. I would have liked to do: `authorize("/subscriptions",hasAuthority("access"))`

Anyway, now I need to make sur that the user is properly authenticated and authorized. I use `ReactiveMetodSecurity` with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('read')")` or `hasPermission(#id, 'entity', 'read:restricted')` directly on the `@DgsSubscription` method.
This works in a way: `hasAuthority` is triggered although it responds with false. As far as I know that's because the `Authentication` object has not been initialized with the token.

[image: Anonymous authentication]

It's most likely because there is no default behavior to intercept the `connection_init` message that contains the token.

**Thus I'm wondering: how can I fetch that `connection_init` message and set the `Authentication` so that it's picked up by spring ?**

Thanks

**EDIT 1**: I've been able to successfully authenticate from a `SecurityWebFilterChain` point of view. The Authentication object however is not available in the `@DgsSubscription`. I can access it though using the workaround explained [here](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/issues/1442#issuecomment-1448038321). That means I now have a solution although this won't be working with a `connection_init` provided `Authorization`. Also it will require me to add a level to my objects to have the PreAuthorization work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is was I was able to do with the auth header in the handshake request:

```kotlin
@Component
class DgsSecurityContextBuilder : DgsReactiveCustomContextBuilderWithRequest<Authentication> {
    override fun build(
        extensions: Map<String, Any>?,
        headers: HttpHeaders?,
        serverRequest: ServerRequest?
    ): Mono<Authentication> = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map { it.authentication }
}

@DgsComponent
class AggregateSubscriptions(val handler: AggregateSubscriptionsHandler) {
    @DgsSubscription
    fun aggregateNotifications(
        @InputArgument id: UUID,
        @InputArgument notificationTypes: List<NotificationType>?,
        dfe: DataFetchingEnvironment
    ) = let {
        val auth = DgsContext.getCustomContext<Authentication>(dfe)
        handler.aggregateNotifications(id, notificationTypes, auth)
    }
}

@Component
class AggregateSubscriptionsHandler {
    @PreAuthorize("@myPermissionEvaluator.hasAuthority(#auth, '$AGGREGATE_READ')")
    fun aggregateNotifications(id: UUID, notificationTypes: List<NotificationType>?, auth: Authentication) =
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .map {
                Notification.Builder()
                    .withAggregateId(id.toString())
                    .withNotificationType(NotificationType.AdvertiserAdded)
                    .withPayload(listOf(KeyValue.Builder().withKey("t").withValue(it.toString()).build()))
                    .build()
            }
}
```

That's the only way I found to currently handle authz in subscription requests

Hopefully we'll get a fix soon that will allow us to use the connection_init message.

See: https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/issues/1442 and https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/issues/450